Start-Process (pnpm run build) This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
I have the next ps1 file created:
$Tool="pnpm"
 $ArgumentList="run", "build"
 $processResult = Start-Process `
        -FilePath $Tool `
        -ArgumentList $ArgumentList `
        -NoNewWindow `
        -PassThru `
        -Wait

If I try to run it on PowerShell such as: .\example.ps1
I got the next error message:
Start-Process: C:\data\example.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |   $processResult = Start-Process `
     |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

But if I run the same file on a Mac PowerShell it runs successfully.
Besides that if I just change pnpm by npm it runs.
The next are my apps versions:
pnpm: 8.3.1
node:20.10.0
npm: 10.2.3
python: 3.12.4
powerShel: 7.4.3
Any ideas?
Thanks!

What is the output of Get-Command -Name 'pnpm'?

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source

ExternalScript  pnpm.ps1                                                      C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\pnp…

Are you using pnpm or @pnpm/exe? What is the extension of the pnpm executable file?

I am using pnpm

While I have no explanation for the error message, note that if pnpm refers to pnpm.ps1, you cannot execute it via Start-Process (with the default configuration, the file would be opened for editing). Since you seemingly want to invoke the command in the same window, synchronously, you could just invoke pnmp.ps1 directly: pnmp run build. That way, you can capture the output, and $LASTEXITCODE reflects the process exit code afterwards. See this answer for background information.

I need to do that from a ps1 file, do you mean to execute this directly on the console? well this fragment of code is a part from another bigger, but I can check what you mean doing some changes in the code

@rasilvap, it should work equally from inside a script.

something like $Tool = "pnpm"
$ArgumentList = "run", "build"
& $Tool $ArgumentList
$processResult = $LASTEXITCODE just curious about the -wait behavior I'm going to test that

I added $Tool="pnpm";
$ArgumentList="run", "build";
$result = & $Tool $ArgumentList
Write-Host "result: $LastExitCode" but not getting the LastExitCode printed

Can I ask something like if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
throw "Tool ($Tool) Failed!!!"
} right ?

Doing this: $Tool = "pnpm"
$ArgumentList = @("run", "build")
& $Tool @ArgumentList
$processResult = $LASTEXITCODE
Write-Host         -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
"result: $( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 ? 'SUCCESS' : 'FAILED' )."
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
throw "Tool ($Tool) Failed!!!"
}
Write-Host "El valor de LastExitCode es: $processResult" is not printing anything

Probably you will need to install or upgrade your pnpm version.
pnpm install

Is you are OS is Windows, check that pnpm is an application.
Get-Command -Name 'pnpm'


If it is not an application, re-install pnpm following this link:
https://pnpm.io/installation


Your symptoms are somewhat mysterious, but I suggest the following:

Upgrade to the current version of pnpm, if possible - current as of this writing is v9.4.0, so yours is quite old.

Make sure that when pnpm is executed, it is pnpm.exe that is executed, and not a pnmp.ps1 file:

That is, Get-Command pnpm should point to an *.exe file, typically $HOME\AppData\Local\pnpm\pnpm.exe; the latter is installed when you follow the official installation instructions.

By contrast, as implied by the output on your system quoted in a comment, in your case pnmp refers to a pnmp.ps1 file.

Leaving aside whether this is an official part of your pnpm installation (perhaps it was in earlier versions, I don't know), you fundamentally can not directly execute a .ps1 file via Start-Process; instead, the default behavior is to open the file for editing.

I suggest removing this .ps1 file, so that it doesn't get in the way of calling the .exe file, which you can do with (Get-Command pnpm.ps1).Path | Remove-Item -WhatIf (remove -WhatIf once you're sure the right file is being targeted). Alternatively, invoking pnpm.exe explicitly, i.e. with the .exe extension - is an ad-hoc workaround.



The arguments you pass to Start-Process suggest that you want to invoke pnmp synchronously, in the current console (terminal). However, for that you do not need Start-Process and using direct invocation is not only simpler, but also allows you to capture the tool's output and have its exit code reflected in the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable. See this answer for background information.

As an aside: an *.exe file, due to of necessity running in a child process, invariably reports a (process) exit code that is reflected in $LASTEXITCODE afterwards.

By contrast, PowerShell runs *.ps1 script files in-process, and $LASTEXITCODE is set if and only if the script exits with an exit call with a numeric argument (e.g. exit 1). Otherwise, any preexisting $LASTEXITCODE, if any remains in effect (in a pristine session, $LASTEXITCODE is initially not defined). If you're dealing with a script about which you don't know whether it sets an exit code, use the following idiom: $global:LASTEXITCODE = $null; ./yourScript.ps1 ...; if ($null -ne $LASTEXITCODE) { <# implies that the exit code was deliberately set #> }

Potentially changing this behavior to be consistent with child-process exit-code reporting is the subject of GitHub issue #11712.





Therefore, I suggest the following:
$Tool="pnpm.exe"
$ArgumentList="run", "build"

# Invoke pnpm synchronously, in the current console.
# * &, the call operator, is needed, because the command is specified 
#   via a variable.
# * @ArgumentList performs *splatting*, i.e. passes the array elements as
#   individual arguments (in the case of *external programs* only, that 
#   would also happen with $ArgumentList)
& $Tool @ArgumentList

# Check the process exit code, reflected in $LASTEXITCODE.
if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw "$Tool failed with exit code $LASTEXITCODE." }

